# MySQL & Play Framework - DB configuration

Tags: mysql, configuration, playframework, database-connection

I'm hosting my play application on a VPS. So I have total control on the configuration of my database, I would like to have a datasource, but with the default configuration of mysql, I run quickly out of connections to my database.

What do you suggest to do? Do I change the number of max connections in my mysql config file? And to how many?

Answer (score 0):

In development mode, play framework recompiles newly edited files and reloads entire platform, which effectively creates new DB connection pool. This technique is called `hot code replace`. I suggest editing mysql configuration file (`my.conf` file located at `/etc/mysql/` on Linux) and increasing `max_connections` property. In my local environment I set it to 500. Even if you set it to higher number, you will still run out of connections, if you dont restart play manually.

Comment: Currently, I have it set to 500.

Comment: Tanks, I will try that

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing it wrong, but, if I spam a little bit a root with a ajax request, I quickly get an exception ("Timed out waiting for a free available connection"), even with "max_connections" to 500. Is there a specific workflow to open and close a connection to the database in Play?